# Unable to unserialize value? On customer edit?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, magento-ee

While Editing The Customer, I'm Getting This Message. How Can I Solve This.?

I found there was an issue with this method in

> vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

[image: Customer Edit Screen]

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: What is stored inside the `$string` when error thrown?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau, I see the same error in Magento 2.2.x, do you recall what you had to do fix this issue?

Answer (score 6):

I also came accross this error today, for me i discovered it was the `Ebizmarts_MailChimp` module that was causing the issue, you can disable the module entirely which corrected the issue or what i chose to do instead was

rename the file

> /vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/view/adminhtml/layoutc/customer_index_edit.xml

to

> customer_index_edit.xml.bak

which stops the ebizmarts customer edit tab loading on the customer edit screen which solves the issue for now (its not a tab i used anyway), i checked and i was using the latest version of the module.

Comment: Thank you. This was also my problem. Perfect

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. Update the mailchimp extension to the current version (look at https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/releases to know what version you must install) and truncate the table mailchimp_interest_group
This is because the way to serialize the interest_group changes, and in the table the saved values are in the old way.

Best

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by overriding one line from `Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Helper\Data`.
You must change:
 `$groups = $this->unserialize($interestGroup->getGroupdata()); to 
$groups =$interestGroup->getGroupdata();`

You can do it by creating another module and inside a di.xml file override this helper.