# I am getting 'Unable to unserialize value' while editing a customer in magento 2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2.2, data-migration, unserialize

I did data migration from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.2 and now I am unable to edit a customer.
I am getting this on customer edit page in admin side.

[image]
I tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/198109/70848) but it didn't work for me.

I added `magento_umask` in Magento root directory with number 002 but it didn't work either

Comment: Did you tried the last solution on that link https://d.pr/free/i/7dz6ix . https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli Yes, I did try it

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli I added 022 number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a 3rd party extension issue
I found this solution helpful.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/257393/70848

Answer (score 0):

Run this query in your database :

```
select * from `customer_eav_attribute` where (`validate_rules` ='');
```

and if it shows any result , fixed it with this

```
UPDATE `customer_eav_attribute` SET validate_rules='[]' where (`validate_rules` ='');
```

CR from [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259036/unable-to-unserialize-value-error-when-customer-data-is-not-display-on-editing-t)

Comment: I didn't get any records after 1st query